# Is it possible to talk about the distance of two random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, random

Suppose that $X, X^\prime$ are two random variables with the same distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Is there anything that we can say about the "distance" between the two random variables?

e.g., $\|X - X^\prime\|$

The thing is that I don't know if the space of random variables is a metric or normed space (never talked about in class), and the types of norms that are typically placed on these functions.

More generally, what does it mean for a function of a random variable to be a Lipschitz function?

Let $f$ be a function of $X$, then when I say that it is Lipschitz, does it mean
$$\|f(X) - f(X^\prime)\| \leq L \|X - X^\prime\|$$
or 
$$\|f(x) - f(x^\prime)\| \leq L \|x - x^\prime\|,$$
where the lower case are the realizations.

Comment: Lots of examples https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance

Comment: Note that $X-X'$ will be a random variable with mean $0$ and variance somewhere between $0$ and $4\sigma^2$ depending on the correlation between $X$ and $X'$